# Asp.net vb.net execution order in a block

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Im trying to get some page to work, but i have a problem and i cant figure out a solution...

I have a piece of code similar to this:

```
Protected Sub chkClient_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkClient.CheckedChanged
    If chkClient.Checked Then
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Processing')", True)
        LoadClients()
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Done')", True)
    End If
End Sub
```

Well, the fact is that the function *LoadClients()* takes a few moments processing and both alerts are fired **after** the function is completed. Why is that? How can i do to have my *"alert('Processing')"* fired before *LoadClients()* function?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What will happen here when you load the page is you will simply get a `Processing` alert, and then your `Done` alert after clicking OK on the `Processing` one.

All of your code is being done Server side, so your telling your page to add an alert to the HTML when it renders, then your telling your page to run `LoadClients()` and then your telling your page to add another alert to the HTML.

the whole `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page,....` lines are simply saying "when this page renders I want it to also render this javascript - it doesn't actually run it there and then.

In order to do this all client side you need to perform an AJAX call to a Web method which will load your clients and return it to your browser where you will process and display it.

Here is a basics tutorial for you, this will give you an idea on how to call a web method with some javascript and AJAX calls. From there the world is your oyster :) : http://trentgardner.net/net/asp-net-webmethods-with-jquery-and-ajax/

Answer (score 2):

Because LoadClients is processing on the server side while your call to RegisterStartUpScript is wiring up code to run on the client side when the page loads.

Here is more info on RegisterStartUpsScript and some examples.

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx)

If you'd like your first alert to show before processing starts you can either use an ajax call which you can utilize many libraries for i.e. jQuery or simply run your alert javascript  before the form is submitted on the click event (or other event) that you are using to submit the form

Comment: You've only answered half the question. You haven't explained how he/she can do what they want...

Answer (score 1):

On your checkbox, add an OnClientClick script:

```
<asp:CheckBox OnClientClick="alert('Processing...'); return true;" ... />
```

Remove the processing script registration from your server side event handler -- you don't need it anymore. That should do the trick for you.

The order of events will then be:

1. User clicks on checkbox
2. OnClientClick is fired and your alert displayed.
3. Postback to server, where your server side click event will be handled.
4. Page re-rendered and your injected "Complete" alert shows up.